# What are ".spmo" files in "dcim/spmo" directory on my SD card?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, motorola-droid-x, images, files

On my SD card, in `dcim`  directory (which is where the images/videos captured with the camera are stored), I also have a subdirectory called `dcim/spmo` which contains a bunch of files with `.spmo` extension.

**What are those `.spmo` files? Can they be safely deleted?**

System: Motorola Droid X, Froyo 2.2 stock ROM, rooted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A short Google search for "spmo file" reveals that these are "SpeedView Meta Object" files and speed up the display of images. They're probably some sort of cache file and should be automatically recreated if you delete them.

Comment: Which app creates/uses them?

Comment: I would assume that the stock apps use them, at least. If displaying images is handled by a system library -- and I would be surprised if it weren't -- probably most apps would use them.